# Not able to post to Django REST API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wanted to create the ViewSet which return list of objects when doing GET request, and in case POST request it will execute the function and only after this will return this list.
I did this like in the documentation, but receiving that "post" is not allowed.

views.py

```
class CloudViewSetHosts(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = CloudModelHost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CloudSerializerHosts

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=True,
            url_path='autodiscovery', url_name='autodiscovery')
    def autodiscovery(self, request, requestDataName=None):

        ... 
        some actions
        ...

        return CloudModelHost.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'hosts', CloudViewSetHosts)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And curl out :

```
curl -X POST  -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4'
```

> http://IP/api/hosts/test/ -vvv
>   *   Trying IP:80...
>   * TCP_NODELAY set
>   * Connected to IP (IP) port 80 (#0)
>
> > POST /api/hosts/test/ HTTP/1.1
> >     Host: IP
> >     User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> >     Accept: application/json; indent=4
> >
> > - Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse < HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed < Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2020 19:20:38 GMT < Server: Apache/2.4.41
> >       (Ubuntu) < Content-Length: 48 < Vary: Accept < Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH,
> >       DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS < X-Frame-Options: DENY <
> >       X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff < Content-Type: application/json <  {
> >       "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
> > - Connection #0 to host IP left intact

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
http_method_names = ['post', ]
```

directly under the queryset and serializer assignment statements:

```
    queryset = CloudModelHost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CloudSerializerHosts
    http_method_names = ['post', ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it didn't help

Comment: Same 405 HTTP response

Comment: ok, so because this is a POST endpoint and you've set `detail=True`, you need to include a pk value in the url. So try to curl `api/hosts/test/{pk}` where `{pk}` is the id/primary key of the object you are trying to create/post. If you do not need or want the pk, try detail=False